# Is it possible to track custom vars in real-time GA view?

Tags: google-analytics

I am starting with Google Analytics and found custom variables very useful (using Classic Analytics now).

Exploring the panel I do see a section for custom variables under the *non-real-time section*. However, if I head to the real-time section, there is no evidence that custom vars are going to appear there (i.e. they can only be seen under the non-real-time section).

Checking the documentation does not clarify this as it does talk about custom vars but does not specify if they appear or not under the Real-Time section. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible for the documentation to list everything that is not the case, so if something is not documented and not visible in the interface it's in most cases safe to assume that it is not there.

[However Google has documented what is visible in the real time reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637?hl=en&ref_topic=1638563) and there is no report for custom vars.